# Magento 2 How to move product option wrapper from FORM?

Tags: layout, magento2.3.1

How to move product option wrapper from FORM?

When I am moving option wrapper form then add to cart is not working and when changed custom option values then the price is not updating

```
<container name="col9_product_page" label="Page col9 Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-sm-9">
                        <container name="custom_product_view" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-view single_product"/>
                        <container name="custom_product_price_addtocart" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_product_price_addtocart"/>

                </container>

<move element="custom_media" destination="custom_product_view" />
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="custom_product_price_addtocart" />
```

and when add to cart and option wrapper both are in FORM then add to cart working and price is also changing when select custom options

Answer (score 0):

Your custom container should be under `product.info`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" ...>
```

**try**

BY default `product.info.form.options` coming at under`product.info` so, you no need to custom option section.

Comment: not getting, still trying to understand your answer. If possible please explain in detail